# How many TCP connections are required to download a file though ftp?

Tags: tcp

Regardless of which mode is used (active or passive mode), the initial connection is done on port 21 (command port). Then a second channel starts (data port) for exchanging the files/data.

Each of the above implies a separate TCP connection and a separate 3-way handshake for each one? Meaning that there are two different TCP connections?

Best Regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTP uses a control connection and for each transfer, a data connection in parallel - so the answer is: two. Both are TCP connections.

If you browse a directory first, each `mdir` requires an additional TCP connection - data connections are only used for a single transfer.

The difference between active and passive mode is the direction of the data connection: with traditional "active" it's connected from the server to the client and with the more common "passive" it's from client to server.

*Edit:* As jonathanjo has noted, FTP's *FXP* mode can use two control connections to different servers to make the servers open the data connection between them and transfer the data without it passing through the client (for a total of three connections). FXP has several potential security issues and isn't very common.

Comment: There's also the rather exotic "third-party" FTP, where a controlling computer C opens two control channels to hosts A and B, and tells one to transfer to the other; this gives three connections C->A, C->B, A->B.  A lot of FTP servers and clients don't support this.

Comment: This probably is FXP connection.